# Adding active class to toggle jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle

Trying to toggle 'active' class to link (.read-more-toggle) that is making panel reveal / hide.

I've got the slideToggle bit working fine. I just need to make the toggle link add class active on click and then remove on click again.

```
$(".read-more-toggle").on("click", function () {
    $('.read-more-content').slideToggle( "slow" );
});
```

Here's a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ndgnsx60/2/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just toggle the class "active" on click aswell.

```
$(".read-more-toggle").on("click", function () {
    $('.read-more-content').slideToggle( "slow" );
    $(".read-more-toggle").toggleClass("active");
});
```